# Can we use Google Fonts when embedded in the same way as when we import

Tags: css, fonts

When we import a font from Google we can use the following to reference it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en" />
```

In this example you can see I'm using a font with 4 font weights

I now want to embed the fonts so I can use them locally. Within google-fonts I can download them but this means I download multiple fonts.

Where as previously I could do

```
.myCss {
    font-family:myGoogleFont;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

Can I achieve the same when I embed the fonts or do I have to do:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myRegularFont;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-Regular.tff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: my300Font;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-300.tff);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: my400Font;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-400.tff);
}
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
// Normal
@font-face {
    font-family: myRegularFont;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400; // 400 is considered normal
    src: url(myGoogleFont-Regular.tff);
}
// Thin
@font-face {
    font-family: myRegularFont;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-300.tff);
}
// Semi-bold
@font-face {
    font-family: myRegularFont;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-500.tff);
}
// Italic
@font-face {
    font-family: myRegularFont;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(myGoogleFont-italic.tff);
}
```

Comment: I'm a little lost as to what this is doing. In each you're using the same font-family. Does this mean each time you wrote font-face, you're essentially adding a new item?

Comment: Correct, every time I initiate @font-face with the same Font Family and different style or weight, it adds that font weight/style to the Font Family. You are free to name the font whatever you like. You can see the same being done in [Google's Font Stylesheet](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&amp;lang=en)